# JavaScript Hangman Game; display only wrong guesses, alert when user wins

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a basic Hangman type game using HTML, CSS, JS.  I have so far successfully been able to create a random word from an array of words, display it to the screen using '_'s for all un guessed letters, and fill in correct guesses by the users keystokes.
I am having trouble figuring out how to :
-display an alert when the user correctly guesses the word.
-detect and display only the wrong user guesses(all keystokes are being displayed now)
Any suggestions would be much appreciated, Thanks!

**- JS CODE**:

```
   var composers =["bach","mozart","beethoven","debussy","stravinsky"];
var randomComposer = composers[Math.floor(Math.random() * 
composers.length)];
var guessComposer = [];

    for (var i=0; i<randomComposer.length; i++){
    guessComposer[i] = "-";
    }
    var el = document.getElementById('guessword');
        el.innerHTML=guessComposer.join(" ");


var wrongGuesses = [];
// var eleme = document.getElementById('wrong');
//      eleme.innerHTML=wrongGuesses;

var guessesLeft = 15;
var ele = document.getElementById('remaining');
        ele.innerHTML=guessesLeft;

var wins = 0;
var elem = document.getElementById('numwins');
        elem.innerHTML=wins;

document.onkeyup = function(event) {

    var userGuess = event.key;

    // el.innerHTML=guessComposer.join(" ");


    for(var j=0; j<randomComposer.length; j++){

        if(randomComposer[j]===userGuess){
            guessComposer[j]=userGuess;
            }
    }

    if (userGuess !== randomComposer[j]){
            wrongGuesses.push(userGuess);
            guessesLeft --;
            var wg = document.getElementById('wrong');
            wg.innerHTML=wrongGuesses;
        }


        if(guessComposer == randomComposer){
            alert("Congratulations, You Won!");
            wins++;
        }

        if(guessesLeft===0){
            alert("You lost, study more music...");
        }

        var el = document.getElementById('guessword');
        el.innerHTML=guessComposer.join(" ");

        var ele = document.getElementById('remaining');
        ele.innerHTML=guessesLeft;

        console.log(randomComposer.length);
}
```

***HTML CODE***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
<head>
    <title>Famous Classical Composers Hangman Game</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/style.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="header">
    <h1>Famous Classical Composers Hangman Game</h1>
    <h3>Press any key to start</h3>
</div>

<div class="wordguess" id="guessword">
</div>

<div class="wrong_guesses">
Wrong Guesses: <span id="wrong">
</span></div>

<div class="guesses_left" > Guesses Remaining: <span id="remaining">
</span>     
</div>

<div class="wins">Number of Wins: <span id="numwins"></span>
</div>




<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/javascript/game.js">
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

For your win check code you are comparing arrays as if they were strings or ints which you cannot do:

```
if(guessComposer == randomComposer){
```

Instead you can use the `every` function that tests a condition for every array element, which also keeps your test relatively simple and close to what it was:

```
if (guessComposer.every((v,i)=>v === randomComposer[i]) ) {
```

This tests if every `v value` in the `guessComposer` array matches the corresponding item at a specific position in the `randomComposer` array.

As for the showing the wrong guesses you need only to show your array as a string in the alert. For that you can use the `join` function:

```
if (guessesLeft === 0) {
   alert("You lost, study more music...\nWrong guesses:" + wrongGuesses.join(' '));
}
```

The `join` takes as a parameter the character that you want to have between every element in the string, which i set to a space `' '`.

Or in other words you could read it as: take all elements and put them into a string and separate them by spaces.

Also the check if the letter guessed was wrong isn't correct as well:

```
if (userGuess !== randomComposer[j]){
```

Which checks if the `userGuess` matches the last letter of the current selected composer. Instead you want to match any of the existing letters with `indexOf`:

```
if (randomComposer.indexOf(userGuess) == -1) {
```

Comment: ....Thank You! that solved the win alert issue....I may have miscommunicated my issue about the wrong guesses issue.....I have a div in the html that I want JS to print out all of the wrong keystrokes (characters that are not in the word) to.  Right now it is printing out all the keystrokes, wrong and right.  This snippet of code was my attempt:                                    
    `if (userGuess !== randomComposer[j]){
    wrongGuesses.push(userGuess);
    guessesLeft --;
    var wg = document.getElementById('wrong');
    wg.innerHTML=wrongGuesses;
    }`

Comment: @AustinTJohnson No problem. Enjoy your coding!

Comment: @Issac between you and some other resources, Ive been able to get the game working 99%.  the last percent that Im stuck with is this.....when I press the start over button, the same word is reloaded ( with "-"s).  there is something in the for loop inside of the reset function that is reloading the same word if  the "start over" button is pressed and the page is not refreashed.......Ive tried many things to correct this and no success yet.....can you give me any pointer? here is a link to my github pages site: https://atjohnson83.github.io/hangman-game/

Comment: You have to re-randomize the composer on your `reset` function with `randomComposer = composers[Math.floor(Math.random() * composers.length)];`. Also this `wg.innerHTML = wrongGuesses;` in the `wrong` function is not correct for the same reasons i gave in the post. You cannot set an `innerHTML` to an array. Instead use the array `join` function to create a string to set in there.